# Reactjs displaying blank screen on android browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an error in reactjs project 
it was working very good but when I browse in android < 5 browsers it display blank screen

you can take a look on this http://accocharity.org

Comment: My first point of call would be to check if you have all the necessary polyfills. checkout https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill.html on how to include it into your webpack bundle.

Comment: Use remote debugging (chrome dev tools) and check if there is any console errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this:

https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html

hope this helps!